# Tab control header with text and image wpf

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, image, tabcontrol

Hy
I have a tab control and I want to put a Text and above it an image. I tried to put them in a StackPanel, but this is too big and when I resize it the image diseapears. When I click on the xaml code on the image I see only an empty box, but the image is not in it. I do not know what is hapenning, I use WPF only for a few days...
Here is my code:

```
  <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60" Width="106">
                    <TextBlock Text=" FirstTab" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="12,15,0,12" Height="18" Width="84" />
                    <Image Source="line.PNG"  Margin="-80,30,663,74" Height="47" Width="74" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
```

I tried to use StackPanel Orientation= "Vertical", but the same thing is hapenning....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get rid of the `Margin` properties on both `TextBlock` and `Image` controls.